# BeautifulSoup4 attribute error

Tags: python

i've been going at this for hours now! i keep getting an error, all i'm trying to do is scrape the name of the product, brand, price, and shipping price, i have successfully scraped all, only issue is when i try and scrape the price and get it to loop through every one of the items on the webpage! i have a separate file in which i successfully scraped the price! This is my code trying to put everything together, and this is the error i get! please help!

```
# coding=utf-8 
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=Property&N=100007709%2050001419%2050001315%2050001402%2050001312%2050001669%2050012150%2050001561%2050001314%2050001471%20600566292%20600566291%20600565504%20601201888%20601204369%20601210955%20601203793%204814%20601296707&IsNodeId=1&cm_sp=Cat_video-Cards_1-_-Visnav-_-Gaming-Video-Cards_1'

# This grabs the webpage and downloads it!
uClient = uReq(url)

# This is so i can read everything out of the url!
page_html = uClient.read() 
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# Grabs each product!
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": {"item-container", "item-action"}}) 

# set up the loop to get the brand of the item!
for container in containers:

    brand_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-brand"})
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]

    title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text 

    price_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-current"})
    price = container.strong.text

    shipping_container = page_soup.findAll("li", {"class": "price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

    print("Product_name: " + product_name)
    print("Brand: " + brand)
    print("Price: " + price)
    print("Shipping: " + shipping)
```

Comment: Your error is the following: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'img'` which means the value of that attribute is None, so you can't get a div of a None.

Answer (score 2):

The `AttributeError` is raised because a tag does not have the subtag you are looking for (e.g. `container` does not have a `.div`).  The cause is because of this line:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": {"item-container", "item-action"}})
```

You are making `containers` all `item-container` divs and `item-action` divs.  The `item-action` divs are not the containers you want to iterate through.  If you change that line to:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": {"item-container"}})
```

then it should parse correctly.

Finally you should change

```
brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]
```

to:

```
brand = brand_container.img["title"]
```